# Объединение звуковых файлов

Tags: java, android, аудио

Нужно объединить несколько звуковых файлов в один, притом объединение может быть и файл на файл.

Пример: пользователь начинает запись нового звука, нажатием выбирает нужные звуки, при этом идёт подсчёт времени в секундах, то есть, если пользователь выберет звук на 6 секунд и через 2 секунды выберет звук на 4 секунды то два звука должны лечь друг на друга.

В конце концов, должен будет сохраниться на устройства один звук с любым расширением (mp3, ogg, wav).